How to save file name with special characters (eg with < > : / \) using pptxgenjs
I am using pptxgenjs to create ppt and trying to save file name with special characters.
E.g.: Filename- Version:1_DataModel. By default, the microsoft power point is not allowing the certain special char in their file name.
Sample Code:
const saveFileName = `Version:1_${stateVariableValue}`;
pptx.writeFile({ fileName: saveFileName });

expected o/p:
Version:1_DataModel
Actual o/p:
Version_1_DataModel
When the file save automatically the : gets replaced with _. Then I tried to manually save the ppt with colon its showed the certain special chars are not allowed.
Is there any way to achieve this?

The issue here isn't with pptxgenjs, but generally with the filesystem not allowing some special characters (as, e.g., described in What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?).
Since the filesystem doesn't allow some characters, there's no way to save a file name with those characters (unless you escape/replace them, as you've seen in the example above).

thanks for ur prompt reply. I gone through the link which you have provided but still am getting confused is that possible programmatically or not , as u knew am using javascript and trying to bind the colon with file name. In that link all are talking linux and windows or operating systems. AM pretty new to all those operating system / ASCII keys. could you please explain?. From ur comment, i get it there is no way to save file name with those chars. But u mentioned something (unless you escape/replace them, as you've seen in the example above). this part i could not get it.,

Javascript is inconsequential here. If you cannot create a file with that name, you can't create it in Javascript either.
